# Linear Time Selection Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, selection-problem

In the linear time selection algorithm which finds the ith smallest element in O(n) time our first step is to divide our unordered set into subsets of 5. Why is the size of the subsets chosen to be 5 and how would the algorithm be affected if I chose a different number. Nothing online describes why this number is the chosen subset size..

Comment: Why don’t you try redoing the analysis yourself with 5 replaced by an arbitrary odd constant?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/87626/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/87992/755

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!